# Using kpathsea command to expand filenames like \includegraphics

Tags: graphics, kpathsea

The `\includegraphics` command from `graphicx` automatically tries different extensions for the figures. For the purpose of automatically processing latex files, I'd like to be able to emulate this behavior using the `kpathsea` command, butthe options in the [manual](https://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Supported-file-formats) don't make it clear how to do this.  Is it possible, or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`graphics` doesn't do a "lookup with wildcard extension" it just loops through a known list of extensions and searches for each possibility in turn.

You can do the same on the commandline

For example

```
$ for e in png eps pdf; do kpsewhich example-image.$e; done
```

returns

```
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.png
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.eps
/usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mwe/example-image.pdf
```

in my texlive 2014 setup, using a bash command line. Most other commandlines
will offer a similar loop construct.